# XML Parser Delegate Function Clarification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I would like to know what each parameter holds value for the following delegate method.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:

Sent by a parser object to its delegate when it encounters a start tag for a given element.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

Parameters

parser

```
A parser object.
```

elementName

```
A string that is the name of an element (in its start tag).
```

namespaceURI

```
If namespace processing is turned on, contains the URI for the current namespace as a string object.
```

qualifiedName

```
If namespace processing is turned on, contains the qualified name for the current namespace as a string object..
```

attributeDict

```
A dictionary that contains any attributes associated with the element. Keys are the names of attributes, and values are attribute values.
```

For More Info plz follow the below link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @iNeo: and if you are in doubt what Namespace is, here is the link: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Answer (score 0):

Go through apple document. It has all these things in brief. Refer it from [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate).